# Страница "прыгает" на последний выделенный элемент после снятия фокусировки с поля поиска по странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема: при расфокусировки поля поиска (Ctrl+F), страница вместо того, чтобы остаться напротив найденого текста, перескакивает либо на последний выделенный (a, input и т.д.), либо, за неимением такового, к верху страницы. 
Это делает поиск текста по странице невозможным.

Вопрос в следующем: почему так может происходить?
По возможности, отвечу на все дополнительные вопросы.

Comment: Без кода самой страницы сложно сделать хоть какие-то выводы. Данная проблема проявляется только в одном браузере? Или в других то же самое?

Comment: @alexoander в хроме и IE все нормально работает.
Кода очень много: весь его сюда пихать смысла нет, а вставлять часть -- я не знаю, какую.

Вообще, поиск осуществляется внутри окна jq dialog, которое расположено на фоне основной страницы.

Comment: Мб просто ссылка на сам сайт? Вы вполне можете его развернуть где-то на бесплатных хостингах. Но не суть. Раз проблема в конкретном браузере, значит код на него влияет в малой степени. У вас нет на странице авто-скролинга или чего-то подобного? (например автоподгрузка контента по достижении конца страницы). А также - проверяли ли вы работоспособность вашего кода на другой версии браузера или вообще на другой машине? Вдруг это просто настройки кривые

Comment: @alexoander сайт является частным интернет магазином. На страницу не попадешь без соответствующих прав, которые Вы вряд ли сможете получить =( Используется шаблонизатор Mako. Да, работоспособность проверялась на других машинах и версиях: ошибка есть. Данные в dialog подгружаются через ajax

Comment: Навскидку: возможно есть какой-то слушатель изменения размеров окна.

Comment: @AleksanderK. Слушателя нет, но у диалога параметр height вычисляется как $(window).height() * 0.9